# Set button clicked when clicking on plugin fake image

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How to make CKEditor toolbar button style set as "clicked" (`cke_button_off` CSS class changed to `cke_button_on`) when clicking on my plugin fake image? Is there is any function or special config possibility?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: You can check my answer here (only a few hours ago) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619223/add-class-to-selected-image-in-ckeditor I think it can help you :)

Comment: Well, can't tell anything at the moment, because your example does not work or I don't understand something. Can't make button be "clicked" when clicking on the fake image.

Comment: The example gives this exact thing, the only difference is that there is no icon there, so you don't see the difference between the `enabled`/`disabled` states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it with this code:

```
editor.on('selectionChange', function() {
    var range = editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0];
    var el    = editor.document.createElement('div');

    el.append(range.cloneContents());

    var $sel = $(el.getHtml());

    if($sel.hasClass('cke_galleries')) {
        $('.cke_button__galleries')
            .removeClass('cke_button_off')
            .addClass('cke_button_on');
    } else {
        $('.cke_button__galleries')
            .addClass('cke_button_off')
            .removeClass('cke_button_on');
    }
});
```

Don't know if it's good practise or not, but it works. If anyone know other possibilities, please let me know ;). The `galleries` string in classes is the plugin name.